# Unable to retrieve video url in a Twitter's post using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, twitter

I am trying to scrape twitter using Selenium in Python. However, I am unable retrieve the video clip's download/streaming url.

Refer below tweet for instance.

https://twitter.com/Tesla/status/1711184330792579093

Is the video source url directly available in the page for me to retrieve?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://twitter.com/Tesla/status/1711184330792579093")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# Accept cookies
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Accept all cookies']"))).click()
# capture and print the href attribute of <a> node
link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='card.layoutLarge.media']//following::a[1]"))).get_attribute("href")
print(link)
```

Console output:

```
https://twitter.com/i/broadcasts/1YqxoDNrdYZKv

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Your answer is indeed resourceful. Here, can you assist with retrieving the download link directly? Is there a workaround to get download url(not the broadcasting url) to stream on a different platform?

I found below link from the api call, but couldn't detect same in Selenium.
https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/1711184835899969536/vid/avc1/640x360/enx-kiIXUAEDZ6NE.mp4?tag=14

Comment: Manually if you open the page on browser, do you have this download link anywhere on the UI? If yes, then we can access it using selenium, if no, am afraid you may not be able to do it with selenium.